# Print layered html5 canvases

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a page composed of multiple layered canvases, which I would like to turn into one image (and then print). So for one canvas it's simple: [capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf).

So what to do with multiple layers of canvases? The only idea I came up with so far is to create another canvas and paint all the layered canvases into this one with ascending z-order. Will work, but taking a snapshot of the original canvases would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Combining your canvases into a single "print" canvas is the way to go.**

BTW, in case you didn't know...

`context.drawImage(imageSource...` will take another canvas as it's imageSource.

Therefore, if you need all your canvases intact (uncombined), just create a new in-memory-only canvas and draw all canvases onto that new canvas in z-index order:

```
var printCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var printCtx=printCanvas.getContext('2d');

printCtx.drawImage(canvasZIndex0,0,0);
printCtx.drawImage(canvasZIndex1,0,0);
printCtx.drawImage(canvasZIndex2,0,0);
printCtx.drawImage(canvasZIndex3,0,0);

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    // print this snapshot image
}
img.src=printCanvas.toDataURL();
```